# Setting a variable within an inherited class

Tags: c#

I have a problem where I have two types of Topping classes, a normal "Topping" class, and one which inherits from Topping and adds a SpiceLevel, Called "SpicyTopping".

My problem is that whenever I construct a SpicyTopping object, the SpiceLevel is set to 0 and I have to manually set it after constructing the object

```
 //Objects
            Topping Mozzarella = new Topping("Mozzarella", 0.40f);
            Topping Ham = new Topping("Ham", 0.60f);
            Topping Eggs = new Topping("Eggs", 0.70f);
            Topping Salmon = new Topping("Salmon", 0.98f);
            Topping Tuna = new Topping("Tuna", 0.80f);
            Topping Garlic = new Topping("Garlic", 0.20f);
            Topping Beef = new Topping("Beef", 0.90f);
            Topping Chicken = new Topping("Chicken", 0.95f);
            SpicyTopping SweetChiliPeppers = new SpicyTopping("Sweet Chili Peppers", 0.31f, 1);//Mild
            SpicyTopping CayenneChiliPeppers = new SpicyTopping("Cayenne Chili Peppers", 0.32f, 2);//Moderate
            SpicyTopping HabaneroChiliPeppers = new SpicyTopping("Habanero Chili Peppers", 0.33f, 3);//Ferocious
            SweetChiliPeppers.ToppingSpiceLevel = 1;
            CayenneChiliPeppers.ToppingSpiceLevel = 2;
            HabaneroChiliPeppers.ToppingSpiceLevel = 3;
```

I don't understand why I have to do this as I think the constructor is set correctly

```
namespace AnotherTest
{
    public class Topping
    {
        //Private Variables
        private string toppingName;
        private float toppingPrice;

        //Properties
        //Topping Name
        public string ToppingName
        {
            get { return toppingName; }
            set { toppingName = value; }
        }

        //Topping Price
        public float ToppingPrice
        {
            get { return toppingPrice; }
            set { toppingPrice = value; }
        }

        //Constructor
        public Topping(string toppingName, float toppingPrice)
        {
            ToppingName = toppingName;
            ToppingPrice = toppingPrice;


        }
    }

    class SpicyTopping : Topping
    {
        //Private Variables
        private int toppingSpiceLevel;

        //Properties
        public int ToppingSpiceLevel
        {
            get { return toppingSpiceLevel; }
            set { toppingSpiceLevel = value; }
        }
        //Constructor
        public SpicyTopping(string toppingName,
                            float toppingPrice,
                            int ToppingSpiceLevel)
               : base(toppingName, toppingPrice)
        {
            ToppingName = toppingName;
            ToppingPrice = toppingPrice;
            ToppingSpiceLevel = toppingSpiceLevel;
        }
    }
}
```

What could the problem be? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor you have the variables defined incorrectly.

```
ToppingSpiceLevel = toppingSpiceLevel;
```

Should be:

```
toppingSpiceLevel = ToppingSpiceLevel;
```

The property `ToppingSpiceLevel` is what you are using to expose the topping spice level, however the private variable `toppingSpiceLevel` needs to be correctly set at the constructor level, as shown above.

Comment: Dammit, 55 seconds :)

Comment: @MarsBars9459 - no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You've capitalised `ToppingSpiceLevel` in your constructor definition.